# Is it allowed to change webfont hinting (font bought on MyFonts)

Tags: webfonts

Let's say you buy webfont on MyFont for use on your website. For example URW Geometric Webfont (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/geometric/licensing.html).

Naturally you want to display it consistent on all browsers and devices. Webfonts tipicaly look great on MacOS (in all sizes), however there is a different story with Windows. Some characters (like “e”, “d”, “b”) seem to be larger than other characters. [See hinting difference - before and after autohinting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKDuP.gif)

I found solution for this issue called autohinting. The process goes like this:

1. **You take .ttf file and apply autohinting to it** - replace the existing hinting with the autohinting information. I used tool “ttfautohint”: https://www.freetype.org/ttfautohint/
2. **Next step is to generate other font formats from auto-hinted .ttf file.** I used tool https://transfonter.org/

**Is this process in accordance to licensing agreement?** 
It states following:

> “You agree not to adapt, modify, alter, translate, convert, or
>   otherwise change the Licensed Web Fonts, or to create Derivative Works
>   from the Licensed Web Fonts or any portion thereof."

Source: https://www.myfonts.com/viewlicense.php?lid=1630

I didn’t change font in any way, I just applied to it autohinting information hence better webfont display on Windows.

Comment: I suggest you open https://www.myfonts.com/contact/ and use their email for customer support and ask them exactly the same question. Why do you think anyone here would know better?

Comment: Thank you for your answer / suggestion. I already did. Didn't receive an answer yet. Maybe someone already had the same problem. Maybe I get an answer and post it here and someone with the same problem will get an answer.